# How to call a parallel data load job from a sequence loop job in datastage

Tags: datastage

I am new to daatstage and working on my first datastage job. I have prepared a data load job which need to take input from a sequence job. The sequence job has table list and I need to pass the table name from table list to load job in a loop. It should pass table name from table list to load job and once load it complete the next table name need to be passed.

However there is error while passing the parameter between the two jobs. Can someone please suggest the steps to pass parameter from one job to another to pick table name.

Answer (score 0):

Examples for that are described in the [Knowledge Center documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/r_ddesref_Examples_of_Using_Loop_Stages.html) or as [video](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-iFmojb2hQ)

Put your job within the loop in a sequence and use $Counter as value for the table name job parameter (as described in the documentation)